# Where datetime between 12 am of column time and 10 am next day of column time

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a column with data type as datetime and the way data is imported is always the previous day to today.

There is not historical data stored in the table - the previous data is deleted before the new data is imported.

That being said I will like to have a where clause written where my ESTEndTime column is between 00:00:00 of the timestamp column and 10:00:00 the next day of the timestamp column.

I've searched but couldn't find anything specific to what I was looking for.

The purpose is to primarily capture the end times of those who work overnight. When the data is exported it always exported as the previous day to the next day, for example October 1 to October 2. This will allow us to see the latest logout times of those who worked overnight. In the example that I just mentioned the data will include everything from 00:00:00 October 1 to 23:59:59 October 2. There is no way for us to limit to a specific time. So using the example when I was hoping to achieve is limit it in a where clause where the time is between 00:00:00 October 1 and 10:00:00 October 2.  The problem is I don't want to use those actual dates as my dates are always changing hence why I am here for some help.

Code that I have but not getting the expected results

```
SELECT timestamp, emp_id, dept, ESTStartTime, ESTEndTime 
    ,CONCAT(emp_id, '-', FORMAT(ESTStartTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')) AS Index2Start
    ,CONCAT(emp_id, '-', FORMAT(ESTEndTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')) AS Index3Stop
    ,CONCAT(emp_id, '-', FORMAT(ESTEndTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd')) AS Index3StopDay

FROM            dbo.[test]
WHERE ESTEndTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, timestamp), 0) + '00:00'
             AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, timestamp), 1) + '10:00'
ORDER BY ESTEndTime DESC
```

Comment: Post the code you wrote so far please.

Comment: "where my datetime column is between 00:00:00 of the datetime column and 10:00:00 the next day of the datetime column." That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes you are correct and what I meant is 'where my ESTEndTime column is between 00:00:00 of the timestamp column and 10:00:00 the day of the timestamp column'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possible way you can try

```
SELECT DISTINCT ee.*
FROM table ee
CROSS APPLY (
   select MIN(timestamp) AS timestamp, NextDate = DATEADD(HOUR,10,DATEADD(DAY,1,MIN(timestamp))) from table
) maxdate
WHERE ee.ESTEndTime BETWEEN maxdate.timestamp AND maxdate.NextDate
```

Comment: Thanks spittingfire. This also worked. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work for you. I declared 2 variables to hold the previous day's date and time and the current day's date and time. I used `GETDATE()` to get the current date and time. I extracted the date part out of it and subtracted a day for the previous date. Then I converted the date to a `VARCHAR` and added the time. SQL Server will implicitly convert the string back to a `DATETIME` value.

```
--Previous day at 12:00am
DECLARE @prevday DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATE,(DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE())))) + ' 12:00AM';
--Current day at 10:00am
DECLARE @currentday DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) + ' 10:00 AM' ;

SELECT timestamp, emp_id, dept, ESTStartTime, ESTEndTime 
    ,CONCAT(emp_id, '-', FORMAT(ESTStartTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')) AS Index2Start
    ,CONCAT(emp_id, '-', FORMAT(ESTEndTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')) AS Index3Stop
    ,CONCAT(emp_id, '-', FORMAT(ESTEndTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd')) AS Index3StopDay

FROM            dbo.[test]
WHERE ESTEndTime BETWEEN @prevday AND @currentday
ORDER BY ESTEndTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Jason.  That solved my issue. Much appreciated